# Как вывести данные расчёт которых происходит в процедуре postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, procedure

Как вывести результат работы процедуры не используя ссылки в параметрах процедуры.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_count_change_points_peers(result_data INOUT refcursor)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    OPEN result_data FOR
        SELECT "Nickname"                                         AS Peer,
               COALESCE(fnc_get_all_change_points("Nickname"), 0) AS PointsChange
        FROM "Peers"
        ORDER BY PointsChange DESC;
END;
$$;

BEGIN;
CALL pr_count_change_points_peers('data');
FETCH ALL IN "data";
COMMIT;
END;
```

Для реализации требуется, чтобы процедура была без параметров. И каким образом интепретируется параметр `data`?

*Cпособа получения таблицы из процедуры отличным от refcursor найдено мною не было .*

Comment: Почему вы хотите для этого использовать именно процедуру, а не функцию?

Comment: @Мелкий.       В ней предусматривается использование транзакций